# Rewriting git common history on one or more topic branches

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

I've encountered a workflow on a new team I'm a little unfamiliar with. The goal for most pull/merge requests is to have a single, squashed commit, in an effort to have a clean history.

That is fine and well, as usually the squash commits occur once a PR has been tentatively accepted (to be merged once squashed and `push --force`ed). Thus, working from the `develop` branch is usually safe.

However, I have a conceptual problem with this strategy when branching work from a commit with a high likelihood of being re-written. This diagram illustrates current and desired states for such a scenario.

[image: crude is as crude does]

1. Work is completed on `feature/foo` and is squashed in preparation for peer review
2. Work begins on `feature/bar` (branched from commit `A`)
3. WIP commits are added (`E` & `F`)
4. Peer review reveals minor changes which are added to the Pull Request (commits `B` & `C`
5. Pull Request is approved, pending squash commit
6. Branch `feature/foo` is squashed and re-written to commit `D`

This is where I'm unsure how to proceed. My question is how can I best "replace" the ancestor of branch `feature/bar`? Some solutions that come to mind are branching off of the new squash commit (`D`) and cherry picking `F..E` and then overwriting (deleting and re-checking out) branch `feature/bar`. Is there a better solution to this i.e. using `rebase`?

Comment: Why don't you just rebase your branch feature/bar onto new branch origin/feature/foo ?

Comment: Rebasing won't give the desired result here because the `A` commit would then appear in the history of `feature/bar`.  The easier way out of this is to not squash commits in `feature/foo` after the branch has already been pushed and made public.  Instead, squash locally and then push.

Comment: i agree with @tim. rebase will not work since it will only "re-order" the commits but not squash them. What you can do is to squash and then use  `git pull --rebase` or to use `cherry-pick` and to bring those commit range to your squashed branch

Comment: Rebasing will work, but it won't give the desired result, because squashing `feature/foo` effectively _rewrites_ the history of that branch, thereby changing the base.  And rebasing is all about sharing a common base which we want to retain.